# Find drawable by integer id from data class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Im writing an app that will record and allow the modification of abstract recipes (literally only an ingredient list [and meta], because it will hopefully help a family-member with how their brain works).

I'm using GSON to read and write those recipes to files, and then bring them into the program as an object, so they can be displayed and modified.

**Recipe.java**

```java
package me.eyrim.foodrecords2;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Recipe {
    @SerializedName("recipe_name")
    private String recipeName;
    @SerializedName("recipe_desc")
    private String recipeDesc;
    @SerializedName("ingredients")
    private Ingredient[] ingredients;
    @SerializedName("recipe_id")
    private String recipeId;

    public String getRecipeName() {
        return this.recipeName;
    }

    public String getRecipeDesc() {
        return this.recipeDesc;
    }

    public Ingredient[] getIngredients() {
        return this.ingredients;
    }

    public String getRecipeId() {
        return this.recipeId;
    }
}
```

**Ingredient.java**

```java
package me.eyrim.foodrecords2;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Ingredient {
    @SerializedName("ingredient_name")
    private String ingredientName;
    @SerializedName("ingredient_drawable_tag")
    private int ingredientDrawableTag;

    public String getIngredientName() {
        return this.ingredientName;
    }

    public int getIngredientDrawableTag() {
        return this.ingredientDrawableTag;
    }
}
```

Below is an example (simple) recipe in the json format GSON produces

```json
{
    "recipe_name": "My test recipe 1 updated",
    "recipe_id": "0",
    "recipe_desc": "this is a test desc for my test recipe 1",
    "ingredients": [{
            "ingredient_name": "Tomato",
            "ingredient_drawable_tag": 700003
        },
        {
            "ingredient_name": "Pepper",
            "ingredient_drawable_tag": 700002
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using a RecyclerView adapter to display the ingredients as a grid. This is my adapter so far.

**IngredientRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```java
package me.eyrim.foodrecords2.recipeviewactivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import me.eyrim.foodrecords2.Ingredient;
import me.eyrim.foodrecords2.R;

public class IngredientRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IngredientRecyclerViewAdapter.IngredientViewHolder> {
    private final Ingredient[] ingredients;

    public IngredientRecyclerViewAdapter(Ingredient[] ingredients, Context context) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public IngredientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ingredient_row, parent, false);

        return new IngredientViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull IngredientViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //imageView.setImageResource(this.ingredients[position]);

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(this.ingredients[position].getIngredientDrawableTag()); // THIS LINE HERE
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.ingredients.length;
    }

    public class IngredientViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final ImageView imageView;

        public IngredientViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_image);
        }
    }
}
```

The line marked `// THIS LINE HERE` is the offending line.

The drawable tags in the json are gathered from `R.drawable.tomato` (etc.).

However, this throws a runtime exception (below):

```
E/im.foodrecords: Invalid ID 0x000aae63.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: me.eyrim.foodrecords2, PID: 3368
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xaae63
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:225)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1428)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.createDrawableIfNeeded(ResourceManagerInternal.java:181)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:146)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:137)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:66)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:91)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:102)
        at me.eyrim.foodrecords2.recipeviewactivity.IngredientRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(IngredientRecyclerViewAdapter.java:35)
        at me.eyrim.foodrecords2.recipeviewactivity.IngredientRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(IngredientRecyclerViewAdapter.java:16)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23143)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23143)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23143)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23143)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23143)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23143)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:798)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23143)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6412)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3684)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3143)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2126)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8653)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1037)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:780)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

My guess is that Android changes the ids at runtime, is there an elegant method of programmatically finding and replacing these? Other than writing in every separate ingredient as a switch to replace the id.
(i.e)

```java
switch (ingredientName) {
    case "tomato":
        ingredient.setDrawableTag(R.drawable.tomato)
    
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: do you want drawable int value from local store drawable file and then you can want to reassign?

Comment: I have understand that you wanted to reassign the value of drawable isnt it??

Comment: I also wanted to know that is your json is static??

Comment: @TanishqChawda I don't want to reassign it, but the drawable int value is not working, at least not as I understand it.

My JSON is not static (well, the testing JSON is, but it won't be once testing is over)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right. Resource IDs are not stable from build to build. Every time your app is recompiled, they might change, so you cannot put them in anything that you save, such as a JSON resource.

I would make your JSON tag the same name as your drawable resource. For example, use `"tomato"` in your JSON for `R.drawable.tomato`.

```java
SerializedName("ingredient_drawable_tag")
private String ingredientDrawableTag;
```

```json
"ingredient_drawable_tag": "tomato"
```

Then you can find your drawable ID by the String name at runtime like this (make sure you keep that Context reference from your constructor in a member variable so you can use it from `onBindViewHolder()`):

```java
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
    ingredients[position].getIngredientDrawableTag(),
    "drawable",
    context.getPackageName()
);
holder.imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: Edit: Removing the code, because it's redundant and doesn't format correctly

The resource ID ends up being something like `2131165347` which implies it's finding it, but a Resources$NotFoundException is still being thrown. Do I need to do anything different to the tag? Currently it's just `tomato`

Comment: The tag being `tomato` is in the style of if I were accessing it via R.
I.E. `R.drawable.tomato`. Is this correct?

Comment: That should work. Not sure what’s wrong.

Comment: I'll have another look into it tomorrow when I'm more awake, I'm sure it's something silly I'm missing

Edit: Thanks for all the help, marked as accepted

Comment: In case you were interested in a follow up. I was right, it was something silly. I had forgotten to tell another part of my JSON which drawable to look for by name, and as a result it was looking for the wrong thing, and then subsequently crashing lol. My bad. Thanks for all the help, the snippet you attached was massively useful, I was on the verge of committing some unholy bodging.